# MongoDB Realm Functions: How to query the document count of a collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, function, promise, realm

I tried implementing using this:

```
const mongodb = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas");
const itemsCollection = mongodb.db("natcocuDB").collection("members");
```

And I tried to put it inside an object

```
let memberToInsert = arg;
memberToInsert.memberID = itemsCollection.count({}) + 1;
```

Then the result is this:

```
memberID : [object Promise]1"
```

So the count function is a Promise. I tried to "await" the count but the function editor of realm produces an error.

[image: Error]

The error says it's missing some ";".

So I tried so separate it by creating an async function for the count.

```
async function getDocumentCount(collection) {
  return await collection.count({}) + 1;
  
}
```

But the result is the same only an object:

```
memberID : Object
```

Do you have any idea how can I get the document count? Thanks!

Comment: Please remember to tag questions with your coding platform so it filters to the users who can most likely help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it already. I just made my parent function async. And the 'await' worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

Db query is an async operation that returns a promise. So in order to get a response from it use `await` or a `callback`.

```
let memberToInsert = arg;
const count = await itemsCollection.count({});
memberToInsert.memberID = count + 1;
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/functions/#behavior

Comment: Hi Tushar. I produces an error if I added the "await". (I edited the question to show the error). So I created a separate async function but the returning value is also an object.

Comment: @nypogi Try printing the output ```async function getDocumentCount(collection) {
  const count = await collection.count({});
  console.log('count', count);
  return count + 1;
}
```

Comment: It is the same. It returns an Object. Not the count. I wonder why is it not waiting for the .count({}) first before returning.